# how to sum amount between two dates using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
<?php
   if(isset($_SESSION['role'])) {
       $role=$_SESSION['role'];
   }

   if(isset($_POST["fdate"])) {
       $fdate=$_POST["fdate"];
       $_SESSION['fdate']=$fdate;
   } else if(isset($_SESSION['fdate'])) {
       $fdate=$_SESSION['fdate'];
   }
   $todate='';
   if(isset($_POST["todate"])) {
       $todate=$_POST["todate"];
       $_SESSION['todate']=$todate;
   } else if(isset($_SESSION['todate'])) {
       $todate=$_SESSION['todate'];
   }
   //$_SESSION["sql"]=$sql;
   $begin =  new DateTime($fdate. " 00:00:00");
   $end = new DateTime($todate. " 23:59:59");
   $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
   $period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);    
   $_SESSION["fdate"]=$fdate;
   $_SESSION["todate"]=$todate;
   foreach ( $period as $dt ) {
      $new=$dt->format("y-m-d");
      $profit_detail=mysql_query("select * from project_detail where date like '%".$new."%' group by project_id ");
      $old_value='0';
      $new_value='0';
      $value='0';
      $balance='0';
      while($row=mysql_fetch_array($profit_detail)) {                                                                                   
?>
         <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
            <td><?php echo $row["date"];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["companyname"];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["project_name"];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["amount_given"];
            $old_value=$old_value+$row["amount_given"];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["total_amount"]; $new_value=$new_value+$row["total_amount"];?></td>
            <td><?php echo  $value=$value+$row["blank"]?></td>
         </tr>
<?php 
      }
   }
   $balance=$old_value-$new_value;
?>
<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
   <td>Total</td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td><?php echo $old_value;?></td>
   <td><?php echo $new_value;?></td>
   <td><?php echo $balance;?></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table> 
</div>
```

I want to sum total no of amount between two selected dates but problem is when i select dates and show the result amount sum only current date amount sum 
where is problem in my sql query or date issue if date issue than all the record shown with amount and details here my output link https://ibb.co/k9yj8v

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user data is **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) and can be exploited.

Comment: Use mysqli, All function of mysql has been depreciated.

Comment: But in my crm everywhere use mysql_query and not possible to use mysqli @ Raghbendra Nayak Systematix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reinitializing value in loop

```
//Add this before foreach
$old_value='0';
 $new_value='0';
 $value='0';
$balance='0';
foreach ( $period as $dt )
                        {
                    $new=$dt->format("y-m-d");
                       $profit_detail=mysql_query("select * from project_detail where date like '%".$new."%' group by project_id ");


                           while($row=mysql_fetch_array($profit_detail))
                           {                                                                                   
                       ?>
                       <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                        <td><?php echo $row["date"];?></td>
                           <td><?php echo $row["companyname"];?></td>
                           <td><?php echo $row["project_name"];?></td>
                           <td><?php echo $row["amount_given"];

                            $old_value=$old_value+$row["amount_given"];?></td>

                               <td><?php echo $row["total_amount"]; $new_value=$new_value+$row["total_amount"];?></td>

                               <td><?php echo  $value=$value+$row["blank"]?></td>

                       </tr>
                       <?php 

                           }
                }
                $balance=$old_value-$new_value;

                       ?>
                       <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                           <td>Total</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                           <td><?php echo $old_value;?></td>
                           <td><?php echo $new_value;?></td>
                           <td><?php echo $balance;?></td>
                    </tr>
            </tbody>
       </table> 
       </div>
```

Comment: the value sum is correct but I am using group by in my sql query but project_id shown two time i have anything changes in mysql query @ B. Desai

Comment: value is sum properly but project id shown two times I want project id shows one time and their value sum like project_id 12 than 12 project id and their value sum it is happen or what i have to do any suggestion my o/p is in below image link https://ibb.co/krSqLa @ B. Desai